# PHPExcel - How to set the default window size

Tags: php, window, size, phpexcel, worksheet

I've looked through the PHPExcel examples and tried searching online, but I can't work out how to set the size of the window when the spreadsheet is first opened - the window is fairly small and I always have to resize it, which becomes a bit tedious when you're testing new layouts :)

In case this is relevant, I'm generating spreadsheets in the Excel 5.0 format (for compatibility reasons).

Hopefully I'm missing something really obvious, but thanks for any assistance!

Comment: This is something that isn't defined by PHPExcel, it's up to MS Excel itself

Comment: Ok, thanks - that might explain why there's nothing in the PHPExcel documentation about it. I'm only opening/saving these spreadsheets myself while I'm setting them up, so it looks like there's no way I can get any control over this if the settings are always picked up from the user's copy of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience excel opens itself to the last size it was when closed cleanly. Try opening  a file, maximizing it,